# ROS Answers SE migration: vslam future

Tags: ros, vslam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
As i could see in SVN - the vslam's latest edition was made 5 months ago.
Does where any plans to continue development of this package?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11984/vslam-future/) by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 471 on 2011-11-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No.

The red-boxed warning on the wikipage is a pretty good clue.

Of course, patches are accepted, if you'd like to continue development. VSLAM has always seen a lot of interest; it just turns out that getting it work reliably, and in general, is extremely difficult.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On a slightly different note - do you guys know why exactly the current VSLAM package fails to do a good job when the robot is moving very fast/ taking very sharp turns?.. I only want to know why this happens on a conceptual level.

I am an undergraduate student and my project is to actually try and improve the performance of VSLAM!.. and I am new to ROS! I would be really grateful to you guys if you could help me out here!

I tried looking into the package files.. but its really tedious and hard to follow! I'm still working through them one by one!

Thanks!

---

Originally posted by [Divya](https://answers.ros.org/users/1220/divya/) with karma: 46 on 2011-11-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-11-18**:
VSLAM works by tracking visual features in the image. When the camera is moving quickly, it gets hard to (a) calculate the features, because of blur (b) match the features, because the matching space is larger and (c) reconstruct motion, because (a) and (b) don't work as well.